# Script for moving all *.512.png to a new folder

Tags: bash, unix, sh, branch, mv

Can you make a script(bash) for moving all the files with the ending *.512.png to a new folder like **res512**(*will be new branch*) (keeping all the subfolders) 
for [this repo](https://github.com/MaximilianGaedig/32-Bit-Game-icons) I tried really long but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Keep in mind, `mv` doesn't create a new directory, so I assume something like `mkdir` would be one of the commands in your scripts. Am I getting this right?

Comment: yes forgotten about this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not very specific with what you're asking.

If you want to move all files that have the suffix `.512.png` from **within your current directory** to a new directory, you can use the following

```
mkdir res512
cp -r *.512.png res512/
```

---

If you want to move all files that have the suffix `.512.png` from **within your directory and all child directories** into a new directory, you can use

```
mkdir res512
for f in $(find -type f -name "*.512.png")
do 
    cp $f res512/
done
```

---

If you want to move all files that have the suffix `.512.png` **including their directory structure** into a new directory, you can use

```
find . -name '*.512.png' -exec cp --parents \{\} res512/ \;
```

---

> Replace `cp` with `mv` if you want to move the files instead of copy them.

Comment: thank you very much, works :) but the subdirectories are not shown

Comment: @MaximilianGaedig if it works, consider accepting the answer :) And as far as the sub directories, you'll need to be a little more lear with what you want.

Comment: The filetree with the folders should be imported

Comment: You said you wanted to move the files that have `*.512.png` as a suffix, i'm not sure how you want the file structure to factor into this.